# When user want to change orientation of phone, my application show incorrect UI. Android

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

When user want to change orientation of phone, my application show incorrect UI.

Phone OS: Android Titanium SDK: 3.0.2.GA

My bug on video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0Yi-6ZKDcw

Code here: http://pastebin.com/qRWmGHrk

Answer (score 0):

This code tells the application to start 150dp down from the top, so in the landscape orientation it puts it lower than you want.  Setup a listener for orientation change and reduce that number or reduce it overall to something that works in both orientations.

```
var viewLoginForm = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor:'#ecf0f1',
        width:'290dp',
        top:'150dp', // <===== location to start drawing the view
        height:'250dp',
        borderRadius:6
    });
```